# When using React with viteJs, no runtime error are shown on the browser's overlay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

my vite.config.js file

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
       
export default defineConfig({
   plugins: [react()], 
   server:{
    port:3000
         }
   });
```

the page will be blank when a runtime error occurs and the error will be displayed in the console only.

Answer (score -1):

Right now, Vite doesn't support showing of runtime errors on browser's overlay. However, there is open feature request issue (https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2076)

Also, before this feature is released, you can add this piece of code in order to enable browser overlay on runtime error (as was proposed in github issue comment):

```
const showErrorOverlay = err => { 
    const ErrorOverlay = customElements.get('vite-error-overlay');
    if (!ErrorOverlay) {return} 
    console.log(err);
    const overlay = new ErrorOverlay(err);
    document.body.appendChild(overlay);
}

window.addEventListener('error', showErrorOverlay) 
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', ({reason}) => showErrorOverlay(reason))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).